# webdriver moves to the next page immediately despite have an implicit wait of 15 seconds

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want the driver to wait for 15 seconds as data takes time to load and I have set implicit wait to 15 seconds for pagination but it doesn't wait for elements to load and goes to the next page.

Note: Implicit wait is working for url but it is not working on pagination.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

url ="http://ethiolist.com/listings"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(15)

listings = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('content-box')


LinksOfBusiness=[]
for box in listings:
    tag = box.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")[1]
    link = tag.get_attribute("href")
    LinksOfBusiness.append(link)
print(LinksOfBusiness)

LinksOfBusiness=[]
condition=True
while condition:
    listings = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('content-box')
    for box in listings:
        tag = box.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")[1]
        link = tag.get_attribute("href")
        LinksOfBusiness.append(link)
        
    try:
        #Click on the next page button
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("→").click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(15)
    except:
        condition: False
```

Answer (score 0):

From experience I had some troubles with Chrome webdriver, not everything was working properly. I would recommend trying with Firefox driver if it's not a problem.

Have you tried the other way in the [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#implicit-waits) ?